# Chrome default popup window position and size

Tags: google-chrome, popup, position, size, default

In setting of a default popup window size/position for Chrome, first open an instance of a broswer. Then press on the upright "Restore" button of the opened browser(Google Chrome). Go make adjustment to desired size and position of the window for the browser. Maximize the main tabbed window of the browser. Open up a popup window. The default popup window should now be in-line with the modified browser window size/position.

Comment: You telling or Asking ..??  :D

Comment: Vote for close : Not a question, it was probably intended to be an answer somewhere else.